# diode circuit without a voltage source

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes, semiconductors

Will there be any current in the given circuit? If current exists then why do they exist and what will be the forward and reverse current and voltage(across the diode)?

As a student of Physics I will love to have an intuitive explanation on the context of electron flow as the reason of current!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There will be only the thermal noise current produced by the resistors. But due to the diode, it will be not spectrally white. The diode is basically a capacitor at low voltages which creates a high pass behavior.

This is ignoring any photo electric effect of the diode

Answer (score 3):

You can be pretty sure that no steady-state current can flow because that would violate conservation of energy*.

Behaviorally, if you look at the I-V relationship described the [Shockley equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shockley_diode_equation), when the voltage across the diode is 0 then the current is also zero.

* In reality if we build this circuit with, say, a 1N4148 and measure the current carefully, most likely we will find that it's rather low but not quite zero. Maybe you can guess how that would happen. Image from Digikey.com
[image]